# Reverse/inverse map with non unique values to multimap

Tags: java

Given `Map<Key, Value>` where `values` may repeat how to inverse map such that result is of type `Map<Value, List<Key>>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using streams, without wildcards, not preserving `null` values:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public static <Key, Value> Map<Value, List<Key>> inverseMap(Map<Key, Value> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())));
}
```